# Cannot define Public Transform Target On Unity C#

Tags: c#

Getting UnityError Saying

> "UnassignedReferenceException: The variable target of Movement_Script has not been assigned

Which is line 5 "public Transform target"

I've tried a lot of things... I can't define it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement_Script : MonoBehaviour {
  public Transform target;
  public float speed = 1;

  void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("up"))
    {
      float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }       
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
    {
      float step = speed * Time.deltaTime * 10;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
        transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime,0 ,-90);    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you assign something to it in the editor? If so, you should probably show it in a screen shot.

Comment: I hope you know that in this way you can drag n drop public objects from unity editor.. I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have not assigned GameObject from the Hierarchy by drag and drop to the script, then you should assign target before you call target.position. For example:

```
void Start(){
    target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
}
```

Then you will be able to get target position from your Update.

Comment: Haha thanks I can't believe i didn't realise i needed to drag and drop to the script...

haha =/